# I want to use the default wordpress password recovery page and not the Tutor LMS recovery page

Tags: wordpress

I want to use the default wordpress password recovery page and not the Tutor LMS recovery page.

I have consulted different codes to not use the recovery of tutor lms but I have not been able to achieve anything.

I want to obtain a solution or code that affects the function.php to deactivate the tutor lms recovery page and use the wordpress one.

I have consulted different codes to not use the recovery of tutor lms but I have not been able to achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I want to advise you that using the standard WordPress password recovery page, you will lose specific links and customizations made by Tutor LMS for its environment.

However, if you're sure about it, you can remove the filters that Tutor LMS use to modify the URL of the password recovery page adding these lines of code in your theme `functions.php` file:

```
remove_all_filters( 'tutor_lostpassword_url' );
remove_all_filters( 'lostpassword_url', 99 );
```

Note that the second line removes all the filters added on "lostpassword_url" filter having priority 99 if any, not only the ones made by Tutor LMS.

Comment: I thank you for your answer and it is as you express, a problem is generated when I apply these codes.

If there was a way to replace the link that appears when hovering over "Have you forgotten your password?", it would be a success. What I need is a kind of redirection.